# how to determine Galois group of the $X^6-10X^3+1$ over rational field Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> How to determine Galois group of the $X^6-10X^3+1$ over rational field $\mathbb Q$?

My thoughts: Firstly, $X^6-10X^3+1$ is irreducible over Q, and then do we need to compute all the roots of this polynomial so that we can get its Galois Group? I am learning graduate-level algebra right now, but I am not sure how to analyze these kinds of question. Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: To analyze the roots, let $y = x^3$, and note that your polynomial $y^2-10y+1$, so the roots are $y = \frac{10\pm\sqrt{96}}{2}$, so $x^3 = 5\pm\sqrt{24}$, and then $x = \sqrt[3]{5\pm 2\sqrt{6}}$.  It'd be good if you could simplify that more though.

Comment: I think that $5+2\sqrt6$ is the fundamental unit of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt6)$ so the cube root Mark gave won't denest.

Comment: If $L$ is the splitting field it is not difficult to see that $Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt6))\simeq S_3$. Dedekind tells me that when we realize $G$ as a subgroup of $S_6$, it also contains a 6-cycle. So it sure looks like $D_6$, doesn't it?